# Google apis DirectoryService returns 403 after multiple successful requests

Tags: c#, web-services, google-api, http-status-code-403, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm building a web service that's sends user information to Google. All is working fine, till I do multiple requests. It fails after 10-20 successful requests.

As login method do I use the Google [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth).

This is code u use to test the service request.

```
while (i < 1000)
{
    Console.WriteLine("================== Start run "+ i + " =======================");

    String serviceAccountEmail = "#####@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"pathtocert", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
        new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { 
                DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser.ToString(), DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUserReadonly.ToString(),
                DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroup.ToString(), DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly.ToString(),
                DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryOrgunit.ToString()
            },
            User = "admin@gmail.com"
        }.FromCertificate(certificate)
    );
    DirectoryService service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = "Bla" });

    UsersResource.GetRequest req = service.Users.Get("test@test.com");
    req.Alt = UsersResource.GetRequest.AltEnum.Json;
    Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User test = req.Execute();

    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + test.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + test.Name.FullName);
}
```

The code runs fine if I place the creation of the service outside of the while loop. When its inside of the loop it will fail after some loops. the are given by the service is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Google.Apis.dll Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Can someone give me a hand? I don't get the error and doent understand why the code sometimes works and sometimes fails.

**Update** Done some test runs again and found out that the BaseClientService.Initializer is the part the gives the error. Also I used fiddler to decrypted the service response. This part explains the json parse error, because the service returns a webpage. The page contained the following message:

> **403.** That�s an error.
>    We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That�s all we know.

So after some time Google blocks my request. My question is why, and why do the send a webpage if the service wants a JSON response?

**Update** After the tip from Alex I looked into the max request for the api, but the limit of the api is by default 15 request/second. The application never fires this many requests. To be sure I set the limit to 50 request/second, but this isn't changing anything.

**Update** After contacting Google looked again into the max request. There is a max User requests of 10 request/second. So to make sure the app did not overuse this quota I build in a timeout after every request of 5 sec, but I still get the same error after multiple loops(this time after 17 runs). As far as my knowledge goes, this can't be a quato over use.

What to try next?

Comment: You're being recognized as a DoS attacker and blocked (requests rate is capped)

Comment: But why do i get recognized as DoS attacker? My request are valid and my credentials are correct. In my opnion its not strange to do bulk request to a service.

Comment: Too many requests per time frame: you probably can circumvent this if you `Sleep` for a couple seconds between each iteration of the while

Comment: This can be a soulution for the test application. But the real project is a webservice how gets called by external code, so i don't have any affect on how many request are done.

Comment: Maybe the limits can be increased/removed by paying but I have no experience with G.APIs